# Handle client timeouts when serving long polling with gevent

Tags: long-polling, gevent

I am using gevent to handle long-polling request. These requests will wait around until an AsyncResult's .get method returns. Then it sends back a result back to the long polling client.

The problem is that the clients connection sometimes times out before the AsyncResult fires. If this happens I get an exception when I eventually attempt to send the response back. Which makes sense as the connection is no longer active. Also I have an AsyncResult object that I should stop cleanly if the connection is no longer open.

I am using pywsgi to handle the restful requests for long-polling. Is there a way to detect within the pywsgi handler that the connection closed, but as an event, because my greenlet will be blocking for the AsyncResult.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: the problem might be on the client side, check your ajax, that function should have the 'complete' field referencing back to that function again